Kotlin BigDecimal remainder() check not working correctly with decimal incrementBy value
I'm having an issue with BigDecimal remainder() check in Kotlin. Even when a quantity should be perfectly divisible by an increment value, the remainder check is failing.
For example, when checking if quantity 6 is divisible by increment 0.5, the code incorrectly throws an exception even though 6 should be valid (as it's divisible by 0.5).
Here's my code:
it.quantity.remainder(product.toIncrementByNumber()) != BigDecimal.ZERO -> {
    val remainder = it.quantity.remainder(product.toIncrementByNumber())
    throw OperationNotAllowedException(
        message = "Quantity for product ${product.name} is invalid"
    )
}

Here's my toIncrementByNumber method

fun Product.toIncrementByNumber(): BigDecimal {
    return when (this.incrementBy) {
        IncrementByType.QUARTER_KG -> {
            BigDecimal(0.25)
        }

        IncrementByType.HALF_KG -> {
            BigDecimal(0.5)
        }

        IncrementByType.ONE_KG -> {
            BigDecimal(1)
        }
    }
}

And here's my product.quantity 

data class ProductQuantity(
    val productId: Long,
    val quantity: BigDecimal
)


in Java - the question is marked with the [tag:java] tag - if (new BigDecimal("6").remainder(new BigDecimal("0.5")).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0) throw new Exception("not thrown"); works as expected (exception not thrown; but thrown if using 6.1 instead of 6)

... BigDecimal#equals does not always work as expected (== and != are even worse, in Java) -- example new BigDecimal("0.0").equals(new BigDecimal("0.00")) results in false (different scale), while compareTo() will result in 0

Who closed the question?

There are 2 problems in your code.
First, using equals() / == to compare BigDecimal is not the correct way if we only need to compare the value. Documentation says:

this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to 2.00 when compared by this method).

In your case we have 0.0 and 0, so they are not considered equal. Instead, we can use compareTo:
val result = BigDecimal(6).remainder(BigDecimal(0.5))
// incorrect
println(result == BigDecimal.ZERO) // false
// correct
println(result.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) // true

Second problem doesn't actually happen in your specific case, but it would happen if using a little different numbers. It is not recommended to create BigDecimal objects from floating point literals. It defeats the purpose of BigDecimal. We use BigDecimal to have a better precision than floating point numbers, but if we started with a double, then we already lost the precision:
println(BigDecimal(6).remainder(BigDecimal(0.1))) // 0.09999999999...

We can fix this problem by creating BigDecimal using strings instead:
println(BigDecimal("6").remainder(BigDecimal("0.1"))) // 0

